# Firemonkey - Object detection

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I use Delphi 10.3.3. for Android app.

On the form I have X rectangle objects.  I have a question like that:
What is the best way to detect who I pressed? 
(Eg, get its name)

Comment: Use the event that is triggered by a press. Which event is it?

Comment: I want to use TAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an event handler for the `OnTap()` event.

In the Object Inspector, assign this event handler to the `OnTap` event of all the rectangles.

Using the `Sender` parameter you can get to the rectangle that triggered the event and find its name. E.g.

```
procedure TForm1.Rectangle1Tap(Sender: TObject; const Point: TPointF);
begin
  ShowMessage((Sender as TControl).Name);
end;
```

A sample procedure to create `TRectangle` instances and assign the event

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  rect: TRectangle;
begin
  for i := 0 to 5 do
  begin
    rect:= TRectangle.Create(Form1);
    rect.Parent := Form1;
    rect.Position.Point := PointF(10 + i * 75, 10);
    rect.Name := 'Rectangle'+IntToStr(i);
    rect.OnTap := Rectangle1Tap;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: yes, but I don't want to do it that way.  the number of objects will be random each time.  How to "listen" globally which object was clicked without creating an OnTap for each object

Comment: Do as I said: create only one event handler, but assign this event handler to all rectangles. Find out which rectangle triggered the event using the `Sender` parameter.

Comment: OK, Thanks I will check.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, but I wonder if there is another method to check "from above" which has been clicked. In AS3, I can create a listener that returns information about what has been clicked, without assigning events to all objects. And this way is cool.

Comment: In different programming languages things are done differently. But something I didn't mention related to your first comment, when you said: *...the number of objects will be random each time...* Obviously this means that you will create these objects in code. The assignment of the event handler is after all only one line of code: e.g. `rect.OnTap := Rectangle1Tap;`. I added a sample procedure of object creation at runtime in response to a button click to my answer.

Comment: Tell me how to safely delete an object (in firemonkey) and the event associated with it?

Comment: I don't understand your question, why would there be something unsafe involved. Just free the object. Btw as this is soon becoming a never ending discussion, I must end it here. Just post a new question if you need further answers. I believe I have fully answered your original question.